# create object according to jsp form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I have class of `Person` :

```
package Model;

import java.util.Set;

public class Person {
    private String firstName ; 
    private String lastName ; 
    private int id ; 

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

I created jsp form with details of `Person`  :

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Create new customer</legend>
        <form action="CreatePersonServlet" method="GET">
            ID : <input type="text" name="id" /> <br /> 
                        First Name : <input type="text" name="firstName" /> <br /> 
                        Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastName " /><br /> 
        </form>
</fieldset>
```

I have `CreatePersonServlet` servlet with the method :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Person newPerson= new Person () ; 


    }
```

what I should write in order that the `newPerson` object will be filled with all his memeber according to the `request` sent from the jsp form . 
in jsp i know it like this

```
<jsp:useBean id="newPerson" class="Person" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="newPerson" property="*"/>
```

but now the member's details not on the `session` but in the `request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can retrieve the **session** object from **request** object using

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

Comment: nice  ... but after I have this session how can I fill to newPerson object without pass one by one of the  member ..  ?

Comment: I know this  .. but how I make same filling of object within servlet (not in jsp)  ?

Comment: inside a servlet you have to go one by one

Answer (score 3):

The scope attribute is used to decide the life of the bean and visibility of the bean.

There are four attributes of the `scope` and they are `page, request, session, application`

The default is `page`.

I think this is what you want:

`<jsp:useBean id="newPerson" class="Model.Person" scope="request"/>`

Unrelated to question: It is suggested to use package name with lower case.